# Mimicry Trait vs Actor Feat

Tags: dnd-5e

Attempting to create a homunculus spellcaster PC, and looking for a way around the fact that a RAW homunculus can't speak. First idea was the actor feat. Can this work in a similar fashion to the mimicry trait (which allows kenku to cast spells)? Any other ideas without homebrewing?

Comment: Your PCs race is a homunculus? Is that a homebrew race? Or did you mean that could a PC's homunculus take the Actor feat?

Answer (score 4):

To play a PC homonculus, you are going to be homebrewing. There are no rules for playing a monster as a character, and there is no officially published homonculus character race.

To double down on that, there is no officially published method that will give a creature that is unable to speak the ability to speak. There are many ways to have something speak on your behalf, but that won't be enough to let you cast spells. In the specific case of the Actor feat, it lets you mimic other creatures' speech, but that ability is useless to a creature that can't speak at all.